# Error while running imagetostring function of pytesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to perform OCR in python. I have downloaded Tesseract and pytesseract using pip install tesseract and pip install pytesseract. But when i call the imagetostring function it shows that tesseract is not installed.
Then i imported the tesseract module and the error went away but then it started showing other errors like configparser.read(_config_file_def) missing 1 positional argument.

Comment: read the pytesseract doc.

Comment: give a path to tesseract exe and then do your functions